# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: Site::$site_model

Tags: codeigniter

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Site::$site_model
>
> Filename: controllers/site.php
>
> Line Number: 13
>
> Site Controller site.php
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function delete_row() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\login\application\controllers\site.php on line 13

My **controller**->Site.php

```
<?php 
class Site extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->is_logged_in();

    }
    function delete(){
      $this->site_model->delete_row();
      $this->index();
    }
    function members_area(){
      $this->load->model('patient_model');
      $data['records'] = $this->patient_model->getAll();
      $this->load->view('members_area', $data);
    }
    function add(){
       $data['main_content'] = 'patient_form';
       $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
    }
    function is_logged_in(){
       $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true){
          echo 'Your don\'t have permission to access this page. <a href="../login">Login</a>';
          die();
        }
    }
}
```

---

My **model** -> site_model.php

```
class Site_model extends CI_Model{
    function get_records(){
          $query = $this->db->get('patient');
           return $query->result();
    }
    function delete_row(){
          $this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3));
          $this->db->delete('patient');
    }
    function create_member(){
          $new_member_insert_data = array(
          'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
          'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
          'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
          'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
          'contact' => $this->input->post('contact'),
          'remarks' => $this->input->post('remarks')
    );
    $insert = $this->db->insert('patient', $new_member_insert_data);
    return $insert;
    }
}
```

---

My **view**-> members_area.php

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header');?>

<div id="main">
Welcome Back, <u><?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>!</u>
<h3>Vision Eye Medical Center Patient Information</h3>

<div id="overflow">
  <table class="features-table">

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Patient Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Contact</td>
            <td>Remarks</td>
            <td>Action</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>          
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach($records as $row): ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->fname;?>
              <?php echo $row->lname;?>
            </td>

            <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->address;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->contact;?></td>      
            <td><?php echo $row->remarks;?></td>      
            <td>View|<?php echo anchor("site/delete/$row->id",'delete');?></td>     
          </tr>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

 </div>   
  <?php echo form_open();?>
     <?php echo anchor('patient/add', 'Add new Data'); ?><?php echo anchor('login/logout', 'Logout'); ?><br>
    <?php echo form_close();?>

</div>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer');?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not loading your "site model" anywhere in code you can do following:

1. autoload it in autoload file.
2. load your model either in constructor of controller, or load it whenever needed by using this line `$this->load->model('site_model');`

More information can be found [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#loading).

Comment: No problem, little sidenote, autload models only that are used in majority of your controllers, do "constructor load" when entire controller is using model, do "load before use" when you use it only in specific method (function).

Answer (score 0):

You need to load model in your controller.

```
 class Site extends CI_Controller{
            function __construct(){
              parent::__construct();
              $this->is_logged_in();
              $this->load->model('site_model'); //Load site_model
             ........
```

Answer (score 0):

In somecase it happens when you don't extract your form data to the model. Try extract($_POST) in your model and don't forget to load the model properly.

P.s.:this was the solution for my error