# Input type file not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

This is the controller. I update the image but I think input type file not accept file or not send the file to the controller so my code was not working well. I think controller code is true.

```
class OurTeam extends CI_Controller {    
public function UpdateTeam()
    { 
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['upload_path']   = '../employeephoto/';
        $config['source_image']  ='employeephoto/';
        $config['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']       = 12024; 
        $config['width']            = 300;
        $config['height']           = 150;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

        $img = $_FILES['fileupdate']['name'];
        if($img)
        { 

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('fileupdate'))
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 

            }
            else
            {   
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                $file_name=($this->upload->data('file_name'));

                $this->load->model('OurTeamModel');

                $id= $_POST['id'];
                $removeimg = $this->OurTeamModel->SelectById($id);
                echo $imgpath = 'employeephoto/'.$removeimg[0]->img;
                if(file_exists($imgpath))
                {
                    unlink($imgpath);
                 }
               else
               {
                   echo "no";
                } 
                  $this->OurTeamModel->UpdateOurTeam($file_name);

                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['upload_path']   = '../employeephoto/'.$file_name;
                $config['source_image']  = '../employeephoto/'.$file_name;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = false;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['width']         = 660;
                $config['height']        = 300; 

                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
                $this->image_lib->clear();
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                $ok = $this->image_lib->resize(); 

            }

        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->model('OurTeamModel');
            $this->OurTeamModel->UpdateOurTeamRecord();  
        }

            redirect('admin/OurTeam');
    } 
}
```

This is view page

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/OurTeam/UpdateTeam');?>

 <input type="file" name="fileupdate" size="20"  id="fileupdate">
 <input type="submit" value="Save" >

</form>
```

Comment: Have you got any error?

Comment: are you printing `$this->upload->display_errors()` on your view after submit?

Comment: No error showing in view page  @GufranHasan

Comment: I write this code $this->upload->display_errors() in view page but error was not show. @Badiparmagi

Comment: you can not show that error in view like that. see [this](https://www.sourcecodester.com/book/5640/how-display-error-message-codeigniter.html)

Comment: I can't be seen any type of error sir @Badiparmagi

Comment: Instead of `$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());` do `exit($this->upload>display_errors());` and tell us if it prints anything.

Comment: @alex this error show Fatal error: Call to undefined function display_errors() in D:\xampp\htdocs\techtoconnect\admin\application\controllers\OurTeam.php on line 214
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function display_errors()

Filename: controllers/OurTeam.php

Line Number: 214

Backtrace:

Comment: Oops I forgot a - should be `exit($this->upload->display_errors());` For the record, I'm betting on the path being invalid.

Comment: okey don't worry  @Alex

Comment: And the output?

Comment: no error print on display @Alex

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Please change to 
        From:

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['upload_path']   = '../employeephoto/';
    $config['source_image']  ='employeephoto/';
    $config['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']       = 12024; 
    $config['width']            = 300;
    $config['height']           = 150;
```

TO:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './employeephoto/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
    $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```

I have checked your code. Please do one thing this article and follow step by step. Hope this will make sense.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/codeigniter_file_uploading.htm

Here is the step by step explanation how to upload a file in CodeIgniter.

Comment: Okay we are very close to solve it @ChandraPrakashPanwar, got go in if condition put print_r($error);exit; and in else print_r($data);exit

Comment: show this error bro    A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: error

Filename: controllers/OurTeam.php

Line Number: 214

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\techtoconnect\admin\application\controllers\OurTeam.php
Line: 214
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\techtoconnect\admin\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849149/a-php-error-was-encountered-severity-notice-message-undefined-property-site

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know what is outputting (maybe take a printsrc and upload to imgur):

```
public function UpdateTeam() {
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['upload_path'] = '../employeephoto/';
    //$config['source_image'] = 'employeephoto/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = 12024;
    $config['width'] = 300;
    $config['height'] = 150;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!empty($_FILES['fileupdate']['name'])) {

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('fileupdate')) {
            echo 'upload failed with error: <br>';
            exit($this->upload->display_errors());
        } else {
            echo 'upload passed <br>';

            $file_name = ($this->upload->data('file_name'));

            $this->load->model('OurTeamModel');

            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $removeimg = $this->OurTeamModel->SelectById($id);
            echo $imgpath = 'employeephoto/' . $removeimg[0]->img;
            if (file_exists($imgpath)) {
                unlink($imgpath);
            } else {
                echo "no";
            }
            $this->OurTeamModel->UpdateOurTeam($file_name);

            echo 'resizing image <br>';

            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['upload_path'] = '../employeephoto/' . $file_name;
            $config['source_image'] = '../employeephoto/' . $file_name;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = false;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['width'] = 660;
            $config['height'] = 300;

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
            $this->image_lib->clear();
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                echo 'image resize failed <br>';
                exit($this->image_lib->display_errors());
            }
            echo 'all good <br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'no file <br>';
        $this->load->model('OurTeamModel');
        $this->OurTeamModel->UpdateOurTeamRecord();
    }

    //redirect('admin/OurTeam');
}
```

Comment: this does not work. show this error> upload failed with error: 
The upload path does not appear to be valid.

Comment: Well then your error is just that. I've done nothing to your code but add a few echos.

Comment: But when I had asked you earlier what the display errors function was printing you said nothing, but it's obviously something important. You need to use a path like `./employeephoto/` **everywhere** you specified a path and make a folder of that name in your directory where index.php is. Then everything should work fine.